# Getting certain array from a multidimensional array

Tags: php, codeigniter

I have multidimensional array which is a query returning the info from a table named 'users'. In another part of my code I need to get the records of only one certain user and I want to take it using the array I mentioned above. It's of type:

Comment: Sorry but I'm struggling to understand what your trying to achieve. Do you mind explaining it again.

Comment: It is difficult to understand what you actually want. Please come up with some more explanation

Comment: We have multiple $key=>$values where the $values are arrays each of them containing element wtith key - "id".I need to extract the subarray with a certain "id" in it. They are unique for every record.

Comment: Can you post your actual full array result?

Comment: It turns out to be fairly easy : foreach ($test as $key => $value) {
    if ($value["id"] == $id) { 
  //print_r($value);
  return $value;
  }

  }

Answer (score 1):

This is probably what you're looking for:

```
$row = NULL;

foreach ($parent as $key => $child)
{

  if (1 == $child['id'])
  {
    $row = $child; break;
  }

}

if (isset($row))
{
  // Stuff to do with the chosen row
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$main = // your array
foreach ($main as $index => $sub) {
  foreach ($sub as $subIndex => $item) {
    if ($item['id'] == xxx) {
      return $main[$index][$subIndex];
    }
  }
}
```

Answer (score -1):

IMO using for loops (rather that foreach) would make it easier for you to reference the variable you need (by using the for loop variable to look up the appropriate row in the array)

HTH,

David

Comment: A foreach is a loop, and foreach has an index in it as well. Please read php.net/foreach before jumping to conclusion.